# Error 403 on image when using Spring Boot + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying out Spring Boot for the first time and I'm stuck with an error 403 that I can't figure out how to get around

I've created an admin page using thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>The Link Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="img/Company-logo-sm-header.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

...
```

The CSS loads perfectly and is located at `src/main/resources/static/css`, the image that's giving me the error 403 is located at `src/main/resources/static/img`

This is my `Application` class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

I've got an MVC Config class:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
  }

}
```

And a security config which I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, `antMatchers(...).permitAll()` to me seems like it should allow images:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/public/**", "/resources/**","/resources/public/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/link").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "**/favicon.ico").anonymous()
          .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
        .logout().permitAll();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
  }

}
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3
I don't have a public directory in `/src/main/resources`, all my static content is going into `/src/main/resources/static`, css is going into the css subfolder, js is going into the js subfolder and they both work fine when doing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>` or `<script src="js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Any idea why my image in `/src/main/resouces/static/img` is giving me an error 403 and the CSS in `/src/main/resouces/static/css` and JS in  `/src/main/resouces/static/js` are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's just your security config that needs work.

You don't need this line since that's just where the static assets are being served from.  It's not a path that will be accessible.

```
.antMatchers("/public/**", "/resources/**","/resources/public/**").permitAll()
```

As for this line, try change `.anonymous()` to `.permitAll()` and you should be able to access the images.

```
.antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "**/favicon.ico").anonymous()
```

Comment: Great stuff, that works! What does the `anonymous()` do? permitAll() I can see is allowing all requests, anonymous I'm not clear about.

Comment: I've never used it myself in any app I've written, but you can consider anonymous authentication as an actual user with certain limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some additions to [above Patrick answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902179/1746258), the answer helped me, but there was another my mistake. When I add

```
.antMatchers("/assets/css/**", "/assets/js/**", "/assets/img/**", "**/favicon.ico").permitAll();
```

error code with `403` changed to `404`. Because I forgot to add

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
}
```

I found this from [another source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775554/1746258).
I hope somebody else will not repeat my mistake.