# Spring Boot not loading static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

There are loads of questions about spring boot not loading static resources and having read them all (almost) I still can't fix this issue. At this stage I have opted not to run with spring boot but I'd still like to know what the issue was. I am using Eclipse, Java 8 and Maven.

I have an application class that looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have created a css file - **`src/main/resources/static/style.css`**
and referenced this from a jsp:

```
<link href="<c:url value='style.css'/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

The page loads but not the css. This is the error - 405 Method Not Allowed

I think think is correct but not sure. All help appreciated.

**Based on some of the comments below this is how things look now.**

My jsp files are configured in src/main/resources/application.properties as follows:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

My Jsp is very simple, and is located in /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="public/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried linking my css file like this:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

My css file, located in webapp/public/style.css, is also very simple

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

My jsp loads but not the css.
I have run my application using various methods including:

From the command line - java -jar contacts.jar

Inside eclipse - mvn spring-boot:run and mvn tomcat7:run-war
Also inside eclipse by right clicking the Application.class file and selecting 
Run As -> Java Application.

I am using Spring Boot Version 1.4.0.RELEASE

Comment: where are your static files located ? src/main/resources ?

Comment: show us how your `jsp` files are configured? and you're sure you have no other static file configuration?

Comment: Your style.css is single quoted. maybe you should try double quotes.

Comment: I've added some additional information above

Comment: Did you figure the solution out? I am surprised that this simple thing was not answered. I am hating spring and java ecosystem right now because it's so bloated and so hard to get even simple things right.

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Location

Put your static resources such as css outside of `src/main/resources`, which is used for application resources such as properties files.

I always put css files under `src/main/webapp/assets/css` folder.

### Configuration

I am using Java config instead of XML, the following snippet shows you how to configure spring boot to recognize and find the css.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware{    

    // view resolver and other confugurations ommitted...

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
    }
}
```

### Access the css

`<link href="<c:url value="/assets/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: None of this is necessary when using Spring Boot, particularly `@EnableWebMvc` which will switch off Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC

Comment: @Minjun.Y this assertion is true for Spring MVC projects. Not for springboot.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thank you for your clarification. I did not completely understand how spring-boot on this subject works and just tried to provide something that somehow works for me. Now I learned.

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte Agreed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*if this dependency is missing, add it to pom.xml file*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not disabling **`WebMvcAutoConfiguration`**

Create the **`public`** folder on the **`webapp`** dir

And on you **`JSP`** page

```
<link href="public/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

> Assuming you **style.css** inside **public** folder 
>   i.e **`webapp > public > styles.css`**

[Here's a docs describing the how to use static content in much more detail.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

Comment: can you add you folder structure

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called  src/main/resources/**static** (or /**public** or just /**resources** or /**META-INF/resources**) . When your project is created, Spring Boot will automatically provide the **static folder** under src/main/resources. For that reason i store all my static resources inside the static folder.
In your case i would place one style.css file in each and every one of these folders and start a debugging process by removing them one by one until ... you know.

[Source](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot):

[image]

Comment: then your classpatch is NOT in your IDE. Must be somewhere in your C drive . Find a way to import your classpath into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for a controller with a RequestMapping with a http method thats not GET, that is accepting your style.css request. This can be any request mapping without "value".

This has happened to me when I moved to spring boot from jetty. In the old jetty solution the static content was served from a different servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with connecting my static resources to my jsp pages and this is what I finally used to get it working with Spring boot 2.0.  You can see my properties and also what the urls look like when mapping to static resources like images or plain html.

Next we need to define the template prefix and suffix for our JSP files in **application.properties**. Thus add:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.context-path=/pdx
```

**http://localhost:8080/pdx/images/thedocks.jpg**  access static resources in src/main/resources/static/images/thedocks.jpg

**http://localhost:8080/pdx/**  loads index.html in *src/main/resources/static/index.html*

**http://localhost:8080/pdx/css/home.css**  loads css class in *src/main/resources/static/css/home.css*

**http://localhost:8080/pdx/h** loads my home controller with @Controller("/") and @GetRequest(“/h”) annotations.

my jsp page loads the static image like this

```
<img alt="the docks" src="/pdx/images/thedocks.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

And make sure your all static files are inside the  src/main/resources/*static/{css,js,other files}* directory.

To get CSS File use spring uri like this--->

```
<spring:url var="css" value="/resources/css"/>
```

then link it like

```
<link href="${css}/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse is mentioned in original question I am linking with this one: [Java class getResource() with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341348/java-class-getresource-with-eclipse)

Sometimes correct configuraton will not work when spring boot jar is run from eclipse.
This can be resolved by adding "main\resources" folder to run configuration classpath manually ("run configurations"->"Classpath tab"->"User entries")